# New Relic integration with goliath

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, newrelic, goliath

I have configured New Relic with goliath as explained [here](https://github.com/adamlwatson/goliath/tree/master/examples/newrelic_stats)

I am using `gem 'newrelic_rpm'`, but not getting stats at newrelic service.

Comment: I am assuming you entered your license key. Which version of the new_relic gem are you using? We had issues with an older version.

Comment: Also have you added trace calls to the rest of your goliath app? Does your newrelic log contain any useful info?

Comment: def response(env)
      trace("Classname#response")
      [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, "Ok"]
    end

Comment: Ya i have added license key. and using trace method as I have mentioned in above comment

Answer (score 0):

We had to add a manual start at the beginning of our app

```
NewRelic::Agent.manual_start({:env => Goliath.env.to_s})
class NewrelicStatsExample < Goliath::API
  # Stuff ...
```

There was a bug in the manual start that was just fixed with the most recent gem.

Also make sure the monitor_mode is set to true for the environment you are testing in the `newrelic.yml` file:

```
production:
  <<: *default_settings
  app_name: New Relic Example App (Production)
  monitor_mode: true
```

Comment: Thanks to look into problem, 

I am interacting with models inside `def response(env)`, 
having models in other directory, 

I am including them(models) in current class,
and when I have removed model interaction then stats are going fine on newrelic, I have tested in development mode, 
I don't know what's the problem, 

@codingFoo Have you any idea about this?

Comment: Maybe the models are changing the middleware chain or they are messing with the list of traces somehow. Order matters in the middleware chain so I would start looking there.

Comment: I am having models in other directory and requires them in action file, is here something wrong?

Comment: It is not having them in another directory and requiring them, but maybe something that the models are doing. Maybe one of your models is changing something, try requiring them one at time. Do all the models cause the problem or is it just one model?